Python matplotlib offset
I'm trying to plot dxf file on matplotlib plot. Shape is drawn correctly but my offset unfortunately no.
This is my shape:
My shape
And code I wrote:
def draw_outside_offset(self, offset=6.0):
    contour_entities = self.get_contour_entities()
    paths = []
    for entity in contour_entities:
        if entity.dxftype() == 'LINE':
            start = entity.dxf.start
            end = entity.dxf.end
            paths.append(LineString([start, end]))
        elif entity.dxftype() == 'CIRCLE':
            center = (entity.dxf.center.x, entity.dxf.center.y)
            radius = entity.dxf.radius
            circle = Point(center).buffer(radius)
            paths.append(circle)
        elif entity.dxftype() == 'ARC':
            center = (entity.dxf.center.x, entity.dxf.center.y)
            radius = entity.dxf.radius
            start_angle = np.radians(entity.dxf.start_angle)
            end_angle = np.radians(entity.dxf.end_angle)
            # Parametric equation for arc points
            t = np.linspace(start_angle, end_angle, 100)
            x = center[0] + radius * np.cos(t)
            y = center[1] + radius * np.sin(t)
            paths.append(LineString(zip(x, y)))
        elif entity.dxftype() == 'LWPOLYLINE':
            points = entity.get_points()  # Extract polyline points
            if entity.closed:
                paths.append(Polygon(points))
            else:
                paths.append(LineString(points))
        elif entity.dxftype() == 'POLYLINE':
            points = entity.get_points()  # Extract polyline points
            if entity.closed:
                paths.append(Polygon(points))
            else:
                paths.append(LineString(points))

        if not paths:
            print("No valid paths created from MILL-E entities.")
            return None
        combined_path = unary_union(paths)

        offset_path = combined_path.buffer(offset, join_style=2, single_sided=True)
        if offset_path.geom_type == 'Polygon':
            x, y = offset_path.exterior.xy
            line, = self.ax.plot(x, y, color='r', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
        self.canvas.draw()

Can someone be so kind and let me better understand what is wrong with my code?
It should draw a offset line around my shape, which is simple 300x300 square with 3 round corners

Your method doesn't seem to be using the offset keyword argument at all. I assume you'll need to add/subtract this as appropriate from the x/y values that you pass to, e.g., LineString, depending on whether it's a vertical or horizontal line or on the left, right, top, or bottom.

Sorry, thats my mistake during copying the code. Its fixed now.

Can you also show the code that actually plots your blue 300x300 square?

It is too long to paste it whole here. Do you think the issue could be there?
It seems to draw each dxf file perfectly.

External offset seems to work ok, it is only problem with internal offsets

It would mainly be useful to see as I don't really know about the DXF format. For the plotting on the original shape, do you essentially do the same thing as in your current code, but without the buffer part, i.e., you extract the contents from the DXF into shapely objects and then get the exterior xy coordinates from that to plot with matplotlib?

Basicaly yes, but i'm skipping shapely in this process. So i'm extracting different types of entities and plot the directly on matplotlib plot.

What happens if you replace x, y = offset_path.exterior.xy with x, y = offset_path.boundary.xy or replace offset_path = combined_path.buffer(offset, join_style=2, single_sided=True) with offset_path = combined_path.boundary.buffer(offset, join_style=2, single_sided=True)?

when i replace it to : boundary.xy i'm getting :
shapely\geometry\base.py", line 229, in xy
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
if i try with offset_path = combined_path.boundary.buffer(offset, join_style=2, single_sided=True). no error is displayed but also no offset shape is draw
